# NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.usertype

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to build a Django app, where two different types of users can register - Tenants and Landlords. I have added a BooleanField in my models.py which will add an entry to DB and in my forms.py I have added a ChoiceField where users have an option to choose who they are.

Upon clicking Register, the account is created but I get an `IntegrityError at /register.`

I'm using Python 3, Django=3.0.3 and django-crispy-forms=1.8.1

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

usertypechoices = [(1,'Landlord'),(2,'Tenant')]

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    usertype = models.BooleanField(choices=usertypechoices)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    # Resize images to reduce memory wasted
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm 
from .models import Profile
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import usertypechoices

class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    usertype = forms.ChoiceField(choices=usertypechoices)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /register
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.usertype

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\RSDEMO\users\views.py", line 11, in register
    form.save()
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 137, in save
    user.save()
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 746, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 795, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 175, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\RSDEMO\users\signals.py", line 11, in create_profile
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 433, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\RSDEMO\users\models.py", line 17, in save
    super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 746, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 784, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 926, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1384, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Maksims\PycharmProjects\FYP\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.usertype
```

Comment: You can fix it by adding a default value for your `usertype` field. I mean you can consider your users being `Tenants` or `Landlords` by default. Or, make your `usertype` field nullable, by adding `null=True` to the field definition.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, do I add default value in forms or models?

Comment: It's best if you add it to your model.

Comment: That worked, but had to change 1 and 2 from usertypelist to True and False.

Comment: Now, the form is setting every user that registers to the default value. Regardless of whether they select 'Tenant' or 'Landlord'. It was working earlier today I'm pretty sure. Would you know is this happening?